# How to access the enum in another class?

Tags: java, groovy, enums

I have the following enum:

```
enum NamesEnum {
    First(1),
    Second(2),
    Third(3),
    Fourth(4),
    static Map<Integer, NamesEnum> valueMap = new HashMap<Integer, NamesEnum();
```

In another class, I want to access the Fourth using `Fourth` so that I can get its value of `4`. In the Enum I have get methods for me to access that enum.

Comment: Syntax is wrong. You need a semi-colon after Fourth, otherwise it will think the map declaration is a value. No closing `>` in the HashMap constructor invocation either.

Comment: it this groovy or java? Why did you put the `valueMap` in your sample for?

Answer (score 1):

If you can declare your enum as `public` like

```
public enum NamesEnum {
   //...
}
```

you can access the contents like

```
NamesEnum.Fourth
```

If you want to get the number `4` from `NamesEnum.Fourth`, you need to expose the stored value somehow. You can do so like this:

```
public enum NamesEnum {

   First(1),
   Second(2),
   Third(3),
   Fourth(4),

   private final int value;

   NamesEnum(final int Value) {
        value = Value;
   }

   public int getValue() { return value; }
}
```

and

```
Names.Fourth.getValue();
```